# Iterating an array of objects using streams

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, java-8, java-stream

I Have this method that displays an array of objects in a document.

```
public File generateODSFileWithTemplate(String fileName, Object[][] lignes, File template) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, JDOMException, TemplateException {

    final Sheet sheet = SpreadSheet.createFromFile(template).getSheet(0);
    sheet.setRowCount(lignes.length);
    
    int column = 0;
    int row = 0;
    //Iterating through the array of Object
    for(Object[] rowObj : lignes){
        for(Object colObj : rowObj){
            sheet.setValueAt(rowObj[column],column,row );
            column++;
        }
        row++;
        column = 0;
    }
    File outFile = new File(fileName);
    sheet.getSpreadSheet().saveAs(outFile);

    return outFile;
}
```

Is there a way to use streams instead of for loop?

Comment: It's inadvisable since you would be using streams to manipulate an existing object outside of the streaming process (which under certain circumstances can have undesirable side effects).  And the  `column increment` could create `effective final` problems.  Now I'm not saying it's not possible, but there is nothing wrong with the way you are doing it (assuming it achieves the desired result of course).

Comment: Also, streams should tend to make the process more clearly reflect the problem statement.  Like grouping items in a map.  I think a stream solution would add unnecessary complexity and tend to muddy the waters so to speak.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think using `Stream API` is appropriate in this particular case. Although you could still improve your for loops by using plain old loops instead of the enhanced ones:

```java
for(int row = 0; row < lines.length; row++) {
    for(int col = 0; col < lines[row].length; col++){
        sheet.setValueAt(lines[row][col], col, row);
    }
}
```